# Both absolute and relative imports failing in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I have a problem where both absolute and relative imports are failing in a non-obvious manner. I have the following directory structure:

```
package1
    __init__.py
    src
        test1.py
        lib
            test2.py
            __init__.py
         __init__.py
```

`Test1.py` has the following code:

```
import os
print(f'CWD in test12.py is : {os.getcwd()}')
from src.lib import test2
```

Test2.py has the following code:

```
import os
print(f'CWD in test2.py is : {os.getcwd()}')
from package1.src import test1
```

If I am positioned in `package1` and I run the following command, I get the result:

```
PS C:\Users\jgoss\Personal\package1> python src/test1.py
CWD in test2.py is : C:\Users\jgoss\Personal\package1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jgoss\Personal\package1\src\test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.lib import test2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

which does not make sense to me as `src` is a package, not a module.

If I change `test1.py` and `test2.py` to use relative imports like this:

```
Test1.py

import os
print(f'CWD in test12.py is : {os.getcwd()}')
from ..lib import test2
```

```
test2.py

PS C:\Users\jgoss\Personal\Infrastructure> python src/test1.py
CWD in test12.py is : C:\Users\jgoss\Personal\package1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jgoss\Personal\package1\src\test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..lib import test2
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

which I cannot interpret since `package1` is a package.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

The only unusual thing that I can see is that there is a mutual dependency between `test1.py` and `test2.py` since each one imports the other.

Comment: Have you tried changing `src.lib` to `.src.lib` or to `.lib` in your first example?

Comment: @mkriegar - Those are relative imports defining packages or modules in the current directory. The modules are in different directories. The first example is demonstrating an attempt to use absolute imports.

Comment: Why is this so hard? Questions like this are asked over and over again and even with years of experience I cannot give a clear answer without guessing or trial & error :(

Comment: The standard documentation fails badly for corner cases which this may be, because of the mutual dependency between modules.